# Checking for matching numbers in the process of apex oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a code that I want to check for variable p_tem whether this variable matches at least one number from my query. I did it this way but it doesn't work out! if my change matches at least one number then it should highlight the message "bed seals!"

```html
Begin
  if :P11_READER = (select SEAL_NUMBER from SEC_SEALS where used = 'Так') then
   
    raise_application_error( - 20001,'bed seals!');
  end if;

end;
```

For example, if in my query, the answer would be: 1,2,3,5. A: P11_READER will be 2, this error should work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of item is :P11_READER, are multi-selections allowed?

If you only want to check your query for a single value you could try something like this:

```html
DECLARE
l_exists NUMBER(30);
BEGIN

select COUNT(*) INTO l_exists from SEC_SEALS 
where used = 'Так' AND SEAL_NUMBER = :P11_READER;

  if l_exists > 0 then       
    raise_application_error( - 20001,'bed seals!');
  end if;

END;
```